# Issue to get/create message in channel

Tags: powershell, graph, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to use graph api with powershell (/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages)
For this i have an azure app with api permissions (delegated and application) "Group.ReadWrite.All and some others. My account is as administrator

I received my token correctly with this

```
$Body = @{grant_type = "client_credentials"; resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"; client_id = 
$ClientID; client_secret = $secret; username = $SPLogin; password = $encpassword }

$res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0" -Body $bodyStr -Headers $head

$headerUser = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer " + $res.access_token };
```

Here is what i received as token

```
token_type     : Bearer
expires_in     : 3599
ext_expires_in : 3599
expires_on     : 1583338248
not_before     : 1583334348
resource       : https://graph.microsoft.com
access_token   : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When i have my token correctly i first try to get all messages in channel (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

```
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$groupID/channels/$chanelID/messages" 
$myPostedMsg = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headerUser -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected and have this error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
"error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "4cd0e36f-2e0c-4712-b613-bcc350595aee",
  "date": "2020-03-04T15:12:53"
    }
  }
}
At line:1 char:16
+ ... PostedMsg = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headerUser -Uri $apiUrl  -Met ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke- 
RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I have the same issue if i try to post a message

```
$body = "{
        ""body"": {
          ""content"": ""Ceci est un message"",
          ""subject"":""Subject"",
          ""contentType"":""html""
        }
      }"

    $apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$groupID/channels/$chanelID/messages" 
    $myPostedMsg = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headerUser -Uri $apiUrl -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"
```

If anyone has already had this issue

Comment: Could you please try doing this using Fiddler or Graph explorer and see if that works fine there? Please share any additional information you see on Fiddler.

Comment: Effectively with graph api explorer it works correctly. I gonna try with fiddler but didn’t know how it works

Comment: Could you please try install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and use the Access token you have to make the post call?

Answer (score 0):

Some apis in teams are "protected". You need to request access from microsoft in advance =>
[Protected Apis in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis)

Comment: Thanks for the link but "Send message" is not protected